# Back button not working in android google mp

Tags: android, android-maps

My simple application has google map with overlay. And a onDraw() method to place a icon on my location. When i click the back button the application doesn't close or go to before activity :( This is the method i used in my activity.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() + 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            gMapView.setSatellite(true);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T) {
            gMapView.setTraffic(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



/* Class overload draw method which actually plot a marker,text etc. on Map */

protected class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
        Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.passenger);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
        canvas.drawText("I am here...", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `return true;` at the end of the method and instead put an `else` statement with `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() + 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            gMapView.setSatellite(true);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T) {
            gMapView.setTraffic(true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

add the following code on the else part of onKeyDown method.

```
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```